# Two CSV files with same column names,. I need to perform linear regression comparing columns with same header name from both files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have two csv files with the same column names in different orders. I need to correlate columns between both csv files between their common headers and plot a correlation plot of the data. For example from file1 and file2 I want to compare the 'ASA' column and form a correlation plot from this. I have a seperate file with all of the column names I need to compare so if can loop through the millions of files I have but pandas keeps telling me I have an attribute error when I add my 'list' to the y = data2.lines.values or x = data1.lines.values. I tried looping and making matching conditions but nothing has worked.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import linspace, polyval, polyfit, sqrt, stats, randn


#File1
data1 = pd.read_csv('sorted_42650files_from_the_1.7chembl_database.csv',low_memory=False) #read large csv filei

#File2
data2 = pd.read_csv('sorted_60kdat_without_duplicates.csv',low_memory=False)

#File3

data3 = pd.read_csv('headers.csv',low_memory=False)
lines = data3.readlines()
#create my x and y column for linear regression comparison based only on the descritor.csv header name


x = data1.lines.values
y = data2.lines.values
print(x)
print(y)



#plot it
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
plt.plot(x,y, 'o', color='purple')
plt.plot(x,intercept + slope*x, color="black", label='fitted line' + ',' + '$R^2$={:.4f}'.format(r_value))
plt.suptitle('MOE ASA+ Descriptor Correlation Plot', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('Ab Initio', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Molecular Mechanics', fontsize=16)
plt.legend(loc=4)
print('$R^2$={:.4f}'.format(r_value))
plt.show()
plt.savefig('ASA+')
plt.close()
```

[file data1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eerpp2dxp384t2t/sorted_42650files_from_the_1.7chembl_database.csv?dl=0)

[file data2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9jrcvdcp2c964v/sorted_60kdat_without_duplicates.csv?dl=0)

[file data3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ss3lf0rleul4ksz/descriptors.csv?dl=0) (all of the headers I want to correlate between the files)

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. It was all about the syntax in the df.values portion of my script. Here is the new script that loops over different headers you want to compare from two files and perform a linear regression on them:

```
import pandas
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from scipy import linspace, polyval, polyfit, sqrt, stats, randn





input_file = "headers.csv"
headerfile = open(input_file,"r")

fields = headerfile.read().splitlines()
#print(fields)

#File1
data1 = pd.read_csv('sorted_42650files_from_the_1.7chembl_database.csv',low_memory=False) #read large csv filei

#File2
data2 = pd.read_csv('sorted_60kdat_without_duplicates.csv',low_memory=False)

#create my x and y column for linear regression comparison based only on the ASA header

for lines in fields:
    #print(lines)
    x = data1[lines]
    y = data2[lines]
#    print(x)
#    print(y)



#plot it
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
    plt.plot(x,y, 'o', color='purple')
    plt.plot(x,intercept + slope*x, color="black", label='fitted line' + ',' + '$R^2$={:.4f}'.format(r_value))
    plt.suptitle('MOE ASA+ Descriptor Correlation Plot', fontsize=14)
    plt.xlabel('Ab Initio', fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel('Molecular Mechanics', fontsize=16)
    plt.legend(loc=4)
    print(lines + '$R^2$={:.4f}'.format(r_value))
   # plt.show()
    plt.savefig(lines)
    plt.close()
```